# SQLAlchemy relationships, when to use which relationship?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have just started learning Flask and using the flask-sqlalchemy package. I have a schema where roles(id, name) and users(id, username, password, role_id) and role_id is a foreign key for roles.id. One to many relationship as one role can be assigned to many users but every user will have a single role.

In the following code,

```
class Role(db.Model):
    # ..
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role')

class User(db.Model):
    # ..
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id')
```

Here, I have established the usage of role_id, but why do we need db.relationship? What is the use of the relationship options and where to use what:

1. backref
2. primaryjoin
3. lazy
4. uselist
5. order_by
6. secondary
7. secondaryjoin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having db.relationship is very helpful in some cases and can help you to avoid long queries.

For example

Without `db.relationship`:

```
role = ...  # some role
Session.query(User).filter_by(role_id=role.role_id).all()
```

Versus with `db.relationship`:

```
role = ... # some role
role.users
```

Concerning relationship options, most useful for you is probably `backref`. It creates back reference property in User model. For example:

Instead of doing this:

```
Session.query(Role).filter_by(role_id=user.role_id).first()
```

You could do this:

```
user.role
```

Concerning remaining options, I suggest to read [official documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship), since it is more informative than anything I could put here in the answer.